# How to fix UTF-8 Firebase Error for Content Script w/ Chrome Extension Manifest.json?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome-extension, content-script, manifest.json

I made a Chrome Extension and am using Firebase to authenticate users. I downloaded the Firebase.js from https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase.js, hoping to add the firebase code to my chrome extension manifest. The Firebase auth is happening in a content script, so it needs to be included in the "js" under "content_scripts".

[Manifest.json Content Script Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aswpS.png)

Instead, I'm getting a UTF-8 error when putting firebase.js.

> Error:
>   Could not load file 'js/lib/firebase.js' for content script. It isn't UTF-8 encoded.
>   Could not load manifest.

I tried using TextEdit on Mac to save the file as UTF-8 - still not luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome. See if you can reproduce it in an older portable Chrome or the new Chrome Canary. You can also search https://crbug.com and report this bug.

Comment: Same problem here with firebase.js

Comment: it sounds a little stupid but could you downgrade to an inferior version of firebase, v2.2.1?

Comment: @DaniGrosu yes, I tried this already - unfortunately, it still doesn't work

Comment: I will post a bug ticket if I can't get it to work on an older Chrome or on Canary....as suggested by @wOxxOm

Comment: I had the same problem with firebase v5.0.1, but after downgrading everything went just fine

Comment: hey @DaniGrosu, which version did you downgrade to? I had the same problem with firebase 5.0.1

Comment: 2.2.1 but it may also work with a higher version

Comment: @DaniGrosu Spark.Bao I looked more into this and some bug in 4.5.1 has caused this UTF-8 error. I would recommend using 4.5.0 and below

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue stemmed from how minifiers/obfuscaters (e.g. uglify) encode certain characters. My development build worked fine, but I got this UTF8 error when I used a minified build.

> Could not load file 'content-script.js' for content script. It isn't UTF-8 encoded.

For me, the solution was to **disable minification**.

It's an acceptable tradeoff because users aren't downloading the code from the server on every page load. It's only downloaded once when the extension is installed or updated. A little extra KB won't hurt anything.